# Reject and requeue message in Mule ESB AMQP Connector with ackMode MULE_AUTO

Tags: mule, amqp, mule-component

My use case is sending mail via SMTP outbound endpoint.

- When everything is OK, the message is acknowledged,
- When validation error (malformed email for example), I want to reject the message,
- When there is a ConnectionException to the SMTP server, I want to wait 1 minute, reject and requeue the message to give it another try.

I use Mule AMQP Connector with `ackMode="MULE_AUTO"`.

- When flow is correctly processed, Mule automatically acknowledge the message.
- When an error occurs in a catch exception strategy, message is rejected and sent to dead letter exchange (no requeue).

I tried using rollback exception strategy but that does not seem to work.

Does anyone know if it is possible to reject and requeue the message ?

*(Mule ESB CE 3.7.0 - Mule AMQP Transport 3.6.2.20150520)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply and comments. I came to the same solution as it seems to be impossible with `ackMode="MULE_AUTO".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is possible.

You need to use `ackMode=Manual`

1) For success scenario : you need to manually acknowledge the message by using `<amqp:acknowledge-message />` at the end of the flow or where you feel in your logic  message can be acknowledged.

2) For failure scenario: Validation error etc, when the exception throws it will be caught in catch exception strategy - use `<amqp:reject-message />` . It helps in rejecting the message.

3)For connection exception: In catch exception strategy  use `<amqp:reject-message requeue="true" />` which will again push the original message back to the same queue. Reference:https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-message-acknowledgement-and-rejection

Both 2nd and 3rd scenarios needs to be handled in exception strategy. So use `ChoiceException strategy` where in use 2 `catch exception strategy` defining one for 'validation error' and other with 'connection Exception'. Reference:https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/choice-exception-strategy

Note: When using `Manual ack`, irrespective of success/failure scenario need to manually acknowledge or reject message externally. Missing any keep the message present in the queue.